# How Java programmatically create an image showing its resolution or multiple resolutions

Tags: java, bitmap, icons, resolution

How can I programmatically create an Image/Icon/Bitmap that shows n number of resolutions in Java using just the SE i.e. no libraries.

e.g. an array of resolutions like

```
[ [640, 480], [720, 576] ]
```

to

[image]

The location of the resolution doesn't matter but would be preferable as shown.

With custom colours/fonts ? maybe even just a line rather than solid fill ?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your question.  You typically don't store all resolutions of an image, you store a high resolution version of the image and scale it down if needed.  If at all possible, you could use SVGs and then resolution doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I want to create a graphical representation of a set of resolutions

Comment: Again, you would need a single image and then scale it to what you need before displaying it to the UI.  See BufferedImage.getScaledInstance()

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the image classes in `java.awt.*` and `javax.imageio.*`:

```
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1024, 1024, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 512, 512);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("512x512", 10, 20);
        // etc..
        ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", new File("C:\\junk\\output.png"));
```

I assume you'll have a loop over your input pairs, then you'll have to fiddle around with the arithmetic needed to get the various bits of text where you want them